# Caching PDOStatement Object in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching, pdo

I am trying to cache the results of a query which won't change very often, if at all. In my class I have a private class variable `private $_cache` and in my constructor I initialize it the way I do with most of my caching:

```
// Setup caching
$frontendOptions = array('lifeTime' => (strtotime('+1 week') - time()));
$backendOptions = array('cache_dir' => '../application/cache');
$this->_cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', $frontendOptions, $backendOptions);
```

Later, in a function I attempt to cache a query's results:

```
$cache_id = 'all_station_results';

if ( ($results = $this->_cache->load($cache_id)) === false )
{           
    // Get all data from stations table
    $sql="SELECT * FROM locations";
    $sth = $this->_db->query($sql);

    // Serialize query results
    $data = serialize($sth);

    // Write to cache
    $this->_cache->save($data, $cache_id);          
} 
else 
{           
    // Return results from cache
    return unserialize($results);           
}
```

This throws an exception:

> You cannot serialize or unserialize PDOStatement instances

So I tried without serializing and I get this exception thrown:

> Datas must be string or set automatic_serialization = true

Now, obviously a PDOStatement isn't a string and I don't see the difference between setting `automatic_serialization = true` and manual serialization.

**How can I cache this PDOStatement object?**

Comment: I don't think you can serialize PDO objects. Why not cache an array containing the results instead?

Comment: What exactly do you want to cache? If the results of the query won't be very large, consider caching the results instead of the statement.

Comment: That's definitely a possibility but was hoping to be able to change any locations in my code where that query is executed and instead call a function which returns the PDOStatement as if I had called `$this->_db->query($sql) but adds the performance benefit of caching. That way the code which follows the queries doesn't have to change because it will be operating on a PDOStatement and won't know the difference.

Comment: Let's say you could cache the statement. Would that then mean that the query would still hit your db each time you fetch the cached statement and use it? Or, would the db get hit only the first time?

Comment: @RobApodaca The `locations` table has 2,792 rows and 14 columns and ends up being a fairly large dataset. And yes, that's with it being normalized...LOL.

Comment: @RobApodaca It would hit it once a week (in case I make changes to my dataset) but otherwise would just retrieve it from a file ready to go.

Comment: @cillosis I see. So, I think that ~2000 rows of data rules out the possibility of storing the results in an in-memory array. Digging a little deeper, is your app actually capable of using all 2,792 rows? Or should you consider adding some criteria?

Comment: @RobApodaca I use all the rows for operations against the current search query such as calculating distances between lat and long points (which I index in a lookup table) to find "related" locations. But you are right, maybe I should look into generating more specific queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't serialize PDO objects at all: they are tightly coupled with the underlying database driver and the connection that is currently open.

You would have to cache an array containing the database call's *results*.That may not necessarily help your performance though: fetching a lot of data from a cache (or storing it all in the PHP script's memory) may take just as long as making the database call, especially if the table is properly indexed.

Using a normal database connection may be the right way to go here; if you have full control over your database, and you're using mySQL, you could also consider looking into [mySQL query caching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html).

Comment: An array may end up being my solution. I would of course benchmark the two options and see which offers the best performance.

Comment: So the query takes on average 0.075 microseconds. When I converted it to an array and cached it, getting the results takes 0.035 microseconds. Not a big performance gain, oh well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Watch out for memory limit issues when loading potentially large arrays.